# Android: Is that possible to implement a flip/page curl from top to bottom like iphone?

Tags: android

I am implementing an app in which i need to flip/pagecurl  a pageview? how can i do that? I didnot find a solution for this. I searched a lot in google? Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities I can think of.

1. You can implement it using [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/). There are a lot of scene's transitions which also contains the page curl animation you describe.
2. There is an open source project called [android_page_curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) which does this.
3. Depending on the android versions you are supporting, you can try [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html) to create that animation.

Comment: Thank you. I will try using an open source project android_page_curl.